# How to mock and test Axios rejected promise?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I created a class called API and it's a simple wrapper around Axios

```
export class API {    
  static get = async (route: string, version: string = API_VERSION) => {
    try {
      return await axios.get(`${BASE_URL + version}${route}`);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
}
```

I'm trying to test the catch branch of the get method:

I tried:

```
describe('API Throws Errors', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject('rejected'));
    jest.mock('axios', () => ({
      get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject('error'))
    }));
  });

  it('get fails', async () => {
    await expect(() => {
      API.get(GROUPS.url());
    }).rejects.toEqual('error');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try wrapping the get in an arrow function? `await expect(() => { API.get(“bad_url”) }).toThrowError(“whatever”)`

Comment: It says "function did not throw" when i do that

Comment: `jest.mock('axios', () => ...` is inefficient in beforeEach. If it's already a mock, you can keep using `axios.get.mockImplementation...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mock behaviour of `axios.get` by using `jest.mock`. Put the below code above the `describe` section:

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject('error'))
}));
```

And you test the error like below:

```js
it('get fails', async () => {
    await expect(API.get("bad_url")).rejects.toEqual('error');
});
```

**Exact Code**

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject('error')),
}));

describe('API Throws Errors', () => {
    it('get fails', async () => {
        await expect(API.get(GROUPS.url())).rejects.toEqual('error');
    });
});
```

**Note**:

If you have another test case that shouldnt be failed, you can just mock it to return `Promise.resolve()`. Or you can just simple clear the mock.

```js
describe('API Throws Errors', () => {
    it('get fails', async () => {
        await expect(API.get(GROUPS.url())).rejects.toEqual('error');
    });
    
    it('should success', async () => {
        Axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(SOME_VALUE));
        await expect(API.get(GROUPS.url())).resolves.toEqual(SOME_VALUE);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but got error: 
    `Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]`

I updated OP to show exactly how I set it up

Comment: please, jest.mock('axios', () => ({
      get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject('error'))
    })); - do this before `describe` section as i said

Comment: also `await expect(API.get(GROUPS.url()).rejects.toEqual('error');` - it should be like this

Comment: Tried this but it didn't change anything. I

Comment: The same error, `Received has type:  function     Received has value: [Function anonymous]`

Comment: i updated the answer, you are sure that you write like that?

Comment: I see, yea that works now. What if I have more tests that are not supposed to be rejected?

Comment: you can use [mockReturnValueOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue) in your test and the mock will respect that single call only. Do multiple of the same to simulate multiple failures if you need to. Additionally you can [reset/clear](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) your mocks in the afterEach method to be safe too.

Answer (score 0):

`toThrowError()` is supposed to be asserted against a function and not result because if an error happens on function call, `expect` doesn't have a chance to be evaluated. It's applicable only to regular functions where an error is thrown. It's not applicable to `async` functions because they don't throw an error but return a result, which rejected promise.

`rejects.toThrowError()` construction is a way how rejected promise can be asserted, an assertion needs to be provided with a promise instead of a function that returns it:

```
await expect(API.get("bad_url")).rejects.toThrowError();
```

Comment: You wouldn't get the same error, `await expect(() => {
      API.get(GROUPS.url());
    }).rejects.toEqual('error');` is not what's suggested in the answer. Please, use exactly the suggested code.

Comment: I got the the exact same error. I updated OP with code and error

Comment: You're still using wrong piece of code. Consider pasting it as is. It should be `await expect(API.get(GROUPS.url())...`, not `await expect(() => { API.get(GROUPS.url()) })...`. It should be provided with a promise, not a function. Maybe the answer doesn't explain clearly why it's so, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the axios for promise rejection like this

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  post: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error(''))),
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error(''))),
  put: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error(''))),
  delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(new Error(''))),
}));
```

This method worked perfectly for me.

Hope this works for you also.